# Como Usar a tag Canonical?

Tags: html-tags

Ja tentei ajuda na net, mas não consigo entender como resolver esta questão.

Por exemplo: se tiver a url - **https://www.seusite.com/** e o google atribuir como canónico **https://seusite.com** , qual a url para adicionar a tag em https://www.seusite.com/index.html?

**https://seusite.com/index.html” /> ?**

Comment: '<link rel=”canonical” href=”https://seusite.com/index.html” /> '?